# Python clean way to convert Counter to csv

Tags: python, csv

I have a file like below.

```
(Time1, Process1)
(Time2, Process1)
(Time2, Process2)
(Time2, Process2)
```

Now I wanted to convert this file to a CSV which should have

```
Time   Process1   Process2
Time1    1          0
Time2    1          2
```

I have tried with a Counter object which gives a data like `Counter({('Time1', 'Process1'): 1, ('Time2', 'Process2'): 2, ('Time2', 'Process1'): 1`

My question is how can I then change this Counter object to above mentioned CSV format?

Comment: your file has actually parentheses like that? Why?

Comment: It's how the file is presentes. Those parentheses can be removed as needed which is trivial.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/117642/writing-a-counter-object-to-a-csv-file-in-python-3) has the answer you are looking for.  They use the built in csv package, and more specifically, the DictWriter method within the csv package.